# How to access parent property value inside a nester getter method of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Below is the code snippet and i would like to access, `propOne.url` inside `propTwoNested`  and it should be a property and not a method.

```js
let obj = {
  propOne: {
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
  },
  propTwo: {
    get propTwoNested(){
      return `SITE URL: ${this.propOne.url}` // need to do some computation. Not the exact logic here. 
    }
  },
}
```

If it try to access it, it throws an error, since `this` context is different. How to get the value of the parent property inside the getter.

```js
obj.propTwo.propTwoNested // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')
```

Is it possible to access it and do not want class based approach.

Comment: You could do `obj.propOne.url` for this particular example

Comment: I have few computation that needs to be done in `propTwoNested` and that is the property i wanted to access it with.

Comment: Does replacing `this` with `obj` not work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry i missed it, Yes, it works when accessing like `obj.propOne.url`.  
Thanks